# WebGL - looking for a way to save json model to vrml format

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, vrml, jsonmodel

Basically I have a model(created dynamically using some inputs) on webgl in the form of array of vertices and an array of indices(indicating the surface to be drawn using the vertices from array of vertices). An array of colors of the vertices.

I need to save this in vrml format for 3D printing. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list of vertices and list of indices into a simple mesh format like OFF or PLY. And then use [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) to load the mesh and export it to VRML.

If what you are looking for is a way to automate the conversion to VRML from the same kind of input, then you can probably write the converter yourself by inspecting how a simple box mesh is exported to VRML by MeshLab: the VRML file still contains a list of vertices and a list of indices (among other things). You could also rely on the C++ library [VCGLIB](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) (the library used by MeshLab), although given how simple the [VRML exporter](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/vcg/code/trunk/vcglib/wrap/io_trimesh/export_vrml.h) is, it is unlikely to be worth doing it.

Finally, since this mesh is to be used for 3D printing, you may have other requirements (do hole-filling for instance) than the export format. In which case, [VCGLIB](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/vcg/code/trunk/vcglib/wrap/io_trimesh/export_vrml.h) may actually come in handy to apply mesh processing operations.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and get back to you if I face any issues.